# JavaFX: prevent shape from dragging over another shape

Tags: java, javafx, collision-detection, shapes, collision

I am doing a JavaFX application and I have a board with multiple shape (circles and rectangle) added to a Pane. I don't want circle to be moved accross rectangle.

Circle are allowed to be dragged using Mouse Event (OnMousePressed,Dragged,Released) while rectangle are not allowed to move.

I am using this code to detect when my circle are colliding with the rectangles.

```
private void checkIntersection(Shape block) {
    boolean collisionDetected = false;
    for (Shape static_bloc : nodes) {
      if (static_bloc != block) {
        Shape intersect = Shape.intersect(block, static_bloc);

        if (intersect.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() != -1) {
          collisionDetected = true;
        }
      }
    }

    if (collisionDetected) {
      System.out.println("Collision detected");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Collision non deteted");
    }
}
```

What I need to do is make my rectangle impossible to drag over while dragging circles. I don't want to send the shape back to his initial location.
Is there a way to do this using intersect or am I missing something?

Comment: @jewelsea you link leads to nowhere.

Comment: @Sedrick, thanks, created a new comment with correct link. Perhaps study the [Oracle Paper doll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/paper-doll.htm) drag and drop sample. Though I am guessing it doesn't fit you use-case exactly. I think your question is a bit too broad to answer as written. For example, what happens when you drag the circle over the Rectangle, does it drop at the edge of the rectangle? does it return to its original position etc?

Comment: @jewelsea Thank you for your help, I will check out the study. I don't want my Circle shape to enter the rectangle shape so theoretically I should not allow my application to drag the circle over the rectangle (It shouldnt be possible). I don't want to return to original position or drop at the edge, I just want to it to block and allow me to drag still and go around the rectangle if I want to.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so easy to answer. You can have a class for instance GameObject. This class contains your Shape. In this GameObject class you have your drag&drop logic. Then u will have a class GameObjectManager which contains list of all GameObjects. And every instance of GameObject will have a reference to this GameObjectManager so knows about all GameObjects as well. So in your move logic you can check if there is some collision between specific GameObject types and if, u can stop moving.

For collision assessment class GameObject contains method  like:

```
protected boolean isInCollision() {
    for (GameObject gameObject : gameObjectManager.getAllGameObjects()) {
        if (!gameObject.equals(this)) {
            if (getView().getBoundsInParent().intersects(gameObject.getView().getBoundsInParent())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In your case you need to loop just some types of objects in this isInCollision method.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share my solution.

I wanted to check the node *before* the movement was done. So I modified the previous solution, to create the following.

**Node Class:** I am working with a custom `Node` class that extends `Label`. The methods used here are those inherited from `Label`.

```
   private boolean hasNoCollision(Node dragged, double x, double y) {
        // For each node
        for (Node n : nodes) {
            // If it is not the same, and future position overlaps
            if (!n.equals(dragged) &&
                    n.getBoundsInParent().intersects(x, y, dragged.getWidth(), dragged.getHeight())) {
                // Then prevent collission
                return false;
            }
        }
        // Otherwise all is good!
        return true;
   }
```